# Thrips in strawberry plants

Tags: insects, strawberries, pesticide

this is the first time I am trying to grow strawberries on a balcony . I built wooden planters for like 60 plants. Since last week all were doing great. They are blooming like crazy and they have a lot of green fruits. I noticed that a lot of plants started having brozne like dry spots on fruits. A didn't know what was going on and after a lot of googling I figured out that my plants are infested with thrips. Just to be sure 100% sure I searched them and found them under leaves and in blooms. I still have a lot of green fruits that are totally fine but I know that if I won't do anything I am probably going to lose all fruits.

My question is how to save my plants. I have mainly everbearings and dozens of june bearings. I know I will have to probably use pesticide to kill the thrips but I know that it shouldn't be used when plants have blooms and fruits?

Is there any option that I would cut all the green fruits and blooms and maybe some leaves, use pesticide and then wait for new blooms and fruits?

thanks for the help